# How do I convert a C# string to a Span<char>? (Span<T>)

Tags: c#, html, string, c#-7.2

How do I convert a `string` to a `Span<char>` in C#?

```
Span<char> mySpan = "My sample source string";
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`Span<T>` and friends are included in .NET Core 2.1, so no additional NuGet package needs to be installed.

[Dan Sorensen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47321870) was correct at that date and based on the preview, but now it is outdated.
For string, the extension methods are `AsSpan` and `AsMemory`, that return `ReadOnlySpan<char>` and `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` respectively.

Explicit `AsReadOnlySpan` is gone, because `string`s are immutable, so it makes no sense to get back a `Span<char>` (that is writeable).

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Was doing a direct search for `AsReadOnlySpan` but was not turning up even though `AsSpan` returns `ReadOnlySpan`, doh.

Answer (score 23):

You need to install the [System.Memory NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/).

There are extension methods for strings called .AsSpan() or .AsReadOnlySpan() to convert a string to the appropriate Span<T>.

Example:

```
Span<char> mySpan = "My sample source string".AsSpan();
ReadOnlySpan<char> myReadOnlySpan = "My read only string".AsReadOnlySpan();
```

Source: [MSDN Channel 9 "C# 7.2: Understanding Span"](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Connect/2017/T125) (around the 6 minute mark)

Update: this answer was correct at the time, but based on a preview version. See [updated answer on this page by gfoidl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49448404/177260) for current procedure.

Comment: Proper thing to do is attribute the SO user that provided you with that link.

Comment: Hans: are you referring to the MSDN source link? I found that one myself. I added it to my answer to remind me where I heard the solution.

Comment: The other Daniel added the NuGet package link. Thank you Daniel!

Comment: Daniel: I wish I could grant you the credit for this answer. You are right that step is vital.

Answer (score 3):

Provided you are on .NET Core/5+ or have the NuGet packages installed (see other answers), you can create a `Span<char>` from `string` as so:

```
string str = "My sample source string";
Span<char> mySpan = stackalloc char[str.Length]; // or `new char[str.Length]`
str.AsSpan().CopyTo(mySpan);
```