# Span<char> and string equality

Tags: c#

When `Span<T>` was announced, I wanted to use it in a parser for my toy programming language. (Actually,  I'd probably store a `Memory<char>`, but that's beside the point.)

However, I have grown used to switching on strings:

```
switch (myString) {
    case "function":
        return TokenType.Function;
    // etc.
}
```

Switching on a `Span<char>` won't work, and allocating a String to compare against kind of defeats the purpose of using a Span.

Switching to using if-else statements would result in the same problem.

So, is there a way to efficiently to this? Does `ToString()` on a `Span<char>` not allocate?

Answer (score 27):

[`System.MemoryExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions) contains methods that compare contents of `Span`s.

Working with .NET Core that supports implicit conversions between `String` and `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, you would have:

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> myString = "function";

if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(myString, "function", StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
    return TokenType.Function;
}
else if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(myString, "...", StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
    ... 
}
```

I'm calling the `MemoryExtensions.Equals` explicitly here because that way it is happy with the implicit conversion of the string literal (e.g. `"function"`) to a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` for comparison purposes. If you were to call this extension method in an object-oriented way, you would need to explicitly use `AsSpan`:

```
if (myString.Equals("function".AsSpan(), StringComparison.Ordinal))
```

---

If you are particularly attached to the `switch` statement, you could abuse the pattern matching feature to smuggle the comparisons in, but that would not look very readable or even helpful:

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> myString = "function";

switch (myString)
{
    case ReadOnlySpan<char> s when MemoryExtensions.Equals(s, "function", StringComparison.Ordinal):
        return TokenType.Function;
        break;
    case ReadOnlySpan<char> s when MemoryExtensions.Equals(s, "...", StringComparison.Ordinal):
        ...
        break;
}
```

---

If you are not using .Net Core and had to [install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47321870/11683) the System.Memory NuGet package separately, you would need to append `.AsSpan()` to each of the string literals.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `ToString()` would cause an allocation because strings are immutable but something you could consider is using the various [MemoryExtensions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions?view=netcore-2.1) methods to perform the comparison. So you could leave your source code being parsed in a `Span<char>` and use code such as the following:

```
System.ReadOnlySpan<char> myString = "function test();".AsSpan();
if (myString.StartsWith("function".AsSpan()))
    Console.WriteLine("function");
```

That will cause an intermediate string allocation for each token (the myString allocation was just to demonstrate) but you could initialize the token table as a once-off operation outside the token parser method. Also you might want to take a look into the `Slice` method as an efficient way to move through the code as you're parsing it.

And thanks to [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg) for pointing out among other things that .NET Core can handle the implicit conversion from `string` to `ReadOnlySpan<char>` so you can ommit the `AsSpan()` if using .NET Core.

Comment: Why via `ToCharArray()`? `ReadOnlySpan<char> myString = "function";`, and then `if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(myString, "function", StringComparison.Ordinal)) { ... }` or `if (myString.Equals("function".AsSpan(), StringComparison.Ordinal)) { ... }`.

Comment: @GSerg is `ReadOnlySpan` only available under .NET Core? I just tried it using LINQPad / 4.7 and it didn't find a reference.

Comment: But `Span` is also only available in Core, for regular .Net you need to [install the nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47321870/11683).

Comment: Just realized I did something dumb and typed your code into a new LINQPad window without the reference. But it still couldn't do an implicit type conversion from string to ReadOnlySpan<char> but making it all a ReadOnlySpan is a good idea which I'll change, I'd just used `StartsWith` because I assume that's what he'd really want for a parser.

Comment: The implicit conversion only works for .Net Core. You have to add `AsSpan()` otherwise.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the help I haven't done anything with core yet and assumed that sort of thing would be the same but have updated with that info.