# Switch statement over ReadOnlySpan<char> is not supported?

Tags: c#

I am playing with Span in C#.

Am I right that I cannot use switch statement with span I have to write methods like this?

```
 private int GetNumberOfLegs(ReadOnlySpan<char> animal)
 {
     if (animal.SequenceEqual("dog".AsSpan()))
        return 4;
     if (animal.SequenceEqual("cat".AsSpan()))
        return 4;
     if (animal.SequenceEqual("spider".AsSpan()))
        return 8;
     if (animal.SequenceEqual("bird".AsSpan()))
        return 2;

    throw new NotSupportedException($"Uknown animal {animal.ToString()}");
 }
```

Is there better way to express this algorithm with Span?

Comment: Did you try to use a `switch` statement? What happened?

Comment: Constant value is expected.

Comment: Could you convert `ReadOnlySpan<char>` to `string` and then leverage switch statement?

Comment: I don't want to convert ReadOnlySpan<char> to string, because it would be allocation on heap and I need to write extra fast realitme code without any heap allocation - no garbage collections.

Comment: The normal switch-over-string in C# works by materialising a `Dictionary<String,Int32>` with an entry for each case block. So to do the same thing with Span<Char> you would need to iterate the span of chars just once to generate a hash-code, then switch on that and only perform a string comparison if there’s a hash-code collission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abusing [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause) could help:

```
private int GetNumberOfLegs(ReadOnlySpan<char> animal)
{
    switch (animal)
    {
        case var dog when dog.SequenceEqual("dog".AsSpan()):
            return 4;
        case var cat when cat.SequenceEqual("cat".AsSpan()):
            return 4;
        case var spider when spider.SequenceEqual("spider".AsSpan()):
            return 8;
        case var bird when bird.SequenceEqual("bird".AsSpan()):
            return 2;
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException($"Uknown animal {animal.ToString()}");
}
```

Comment: This has `O(n * m)` runtime (where `n` is the length of the string and `m` is the number of cases) - it's the same thing as a bunch of `if/else if` statements. I think `switch` should be reserved for near-`O(1)` cases.

Comment: @Dai I agree, but I can't think of a better way to use `switch` here, which is kind of an academic exercise at this point.

Comment: SequenceEquals is slower than MemoryExtensions.Equals https://stackoverflow.com/a/52680582/56621