# How to use a variable into a "case" of a switch case

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm a beginner in C# and I'm developing an HMI (WinForms).

I have a DataGridView filled with data and some column with buttons.
When I click on a button of the column, the CellContentClick event is triggering and I would like to get the precise column where the user clicked, using a switch case:
(simplified code)

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0) // if cell button
    {
        switch (e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case Column1.Index: // <- not building because Column1.Index is a variable
                // do something
                break;
            case Column2.Index: 
                // do something
                break;
            //etc
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `ColumnX.Index` can not be put into the `case` condition because it's a variable. Of course, I could use directly the number of the column index, but since I'm developing and always moving the columns, I would like to keep the `ColumnX.Index` way.

Comment: This is not possible. Use if .. else if .. else instead.

Comment: or use the columns name, they should stay fixed, or use an id tag, anything that stays constant. A switch is a dictionary, and the keys of the dictionary are not allowed to change.

Comment: What is an HMI?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like to keep the switch case method, because with the if/else if, it will get a bit messy. Maybe there is a way to use an intermediate value which is getting prior ColumnX.Index ?

Comment: Pall Due: Human Machine Interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use something else - an `else` or `else if` statement could work for you. You could also use an `enum` of the expected value and reference them in your `case` statement.

Comment: Let me know if you need some assistance with this code.

Comment: @PLB Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Switches cannot have dynamic evaluated statements in the case statement. They must be statically evaluated.

Below post explain it why :

[C# switch statement limitations - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905/c-sharp-switch-statement-limitations-why)

Also you can use alternative ways, as explained in below link:

[Is there a better alternative than this to 'switch on type'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need in your particular case, you could also make use of "Tag" property of the column (it's on `DataGridViewBand` that is base for `DataGridViewColumn`). When I worked with forms I used to place there operation code that the button is supposed to trigger.
So on the column you place for example `Tag="UpdateRecord"` and in the code you can have

```
switch (column.Tag as string)
{
    case "UpdateRecord":
        // Update code
        break;
    // Other cases
}
```

This way you can easily reorder columns of your grid without playing with fixing those switches.
Also (as the next step towards cleaner code) you could put "UpdateRecord" text into `const` in some class and use it in column definition and switch definition.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to keep the switch case method

Well, you can [abuse pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853930/11683):

```cs
switch (c.ColumnIndex)
{
    case int i when i == Column1.Index:
        // do something
        break;
    case int i when i == Column2.Index:
        // do something
        break;
    //etc
    default: break;
}
```

but I would not recommend.